# Editing WordPress Site Locally

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a WordPress site, which is saved on localhost and have been editing elements of my site, such as font color etc in 'Customiser' on WordPress. However, it has become clear that you are restricted when editing this way. I am also used to creating pure HTML sites, so would rather edit the code locally.

I have all of the files I need downloaded and have started to edit the style.css but my question is, what is the best way to go about editing the php files and finding what you want?

For example: I know that if I go to 'footer.php', this is where I would edit the footer content. Is there a general way of knowing which section will be found in which PHP file, possibly using 'inspect elements'?

I know it is a broad question, but any advice when it comes to local WordPress sites would be appreciated. There does not appear to be much info out there about how to edit once you have made your WP site local.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is likely more on-topic on [wp.se](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very broad, but I will do my best to answer. You mentioned there not being much out there when it comes to editing WP locally. I want to point out that there is a huge WP community online and that you can refer to the WordPress Codex for most answers. With that said, you can create custom page templates fairly easy. This will allow you to completely control the structure of the content. All of the documentation is located here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use
For existing sections of your site, you will need to just explore the files to get an idea of where everything is, as themes can vary in the way they are laid out. Unfortunately, I will not be able to help you more without more details.

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful. My brain has become so jumbled with it, that sometimes it really helps to get some fresh ideas. Will look into that - thanks!